# Angular 7 and Objects search how to find strict values

Tags: arrays, angular, object, angular7

I am searching for a value of `yes` in the field `hhead` of an object returned from server:

```
Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
    if (this.data[key].hhead === 'yes') {
    console.log('Yes '+(this.data[key].hhead === 'yes'))
    this.snackBar.open('This household already have ' + this.data[key].far + ' ' + this.data[key].lar + ' (id: ' + this.data[key].iid + ' ) as a head of household', 'Close', {
        panelClass: 'error'
    });
    }
    else {
    console.log('No '+(this.data[key].hhead === 'no'))
    if (data['age'] <= 17 && data['age'] < this.maxAge && (selectedFr == "Head Of Household")) {

        let message = 'This individual is not the oldest in his family to be the head of household. Do you want to complete this action ?';
        this.openDialog(message, updateType, ind_id, newSts, newMs, newFr, newHH, oldHH, missingData);
    }
    }
});
```

The problem with this script is that both `if` and `else` are true. So both scripts will run.

The reason is that, at the first condition, once it finds a `yes` value, the condition turn true.

And the second, once it finds `no` it will run.

The array is like:

[image]

So what I need is **if an array only contains** `no` in all rows, to run the `else` part. And if it found **at least** `yes` to run the first condition.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to attack the problem from the wrong angle. You have to scan the collection first and then run your code:

```
var mached = this.data.every(t => t.hhead == 'yes'); //this will print true

Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
    if (mached) {
        console.log('Yes '+(this.data[key].hhead === 'yes'))
        this.snackBar.open('This household already have ' + this.data[key].far + ' ' + this.data[key].lar + ' (id: ' + this.data[key].iid + ' ) as a head of household', 'Close', {
           panelClass: 'error'
        });
    } else {
        console.log('No '+(this.data[key].hhead === 'no'))
        if (data['age'] <= 17 && data['age'] < this.maxAge && (selectedFr == "Head Of Household")) {

        let message = 'This individual is not the oldest in his family to be the head of household. Do you want to complete this action ?';
        this.openDialog(message, updateType, ind_id, newSts, newMs, newFr, newHH, oldHH, missingData);
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: I will check it on monday and get back to you.